# Как использовать [skyline]

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, подскажите, как использовать [skyline] на примере?

Хочу достичь такого же эффекта как на http://maxmert.com/components#skylineCommon.

Хочу создать эффект рандомного появления картинки на странице, что бы при скроллинге они рандомно появлялись на странице как показано в примере по сселке http://maxmert.com/components#skylineCommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути просто рандомишь порядок картинок, пихаешь их на сайт с отступом в половину картинки и рамерами `0х0`. И добавляешь анимацию, например на `transitions`:

Ну и чтоб прям как на примере - ты должен отслеживать на какой высоте ты сейчас на сайте и какие картинки находятся на этой же высоте.

Примерчик вот накидал, посмотри: http://jsfiddle.net/JG4Fg/